# can kernel identify which userapp got killed/closed, among few apps it is serving

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, userspace, os-userspace

I'm writing a linux kernel driver, which creates a char device file "/dev/my_file".
Multiple userspace applications do `open()` of this file and use the `ioctl` cmd provided to register app specific data. IOCTL also provides for deregister cmd, which apps can use and deregister themselves(kernel drv removes app data, delete any memory allocation etc) when doing clean exit.
However, if an application gets killed after doing `open()` and `ioctl` register cmd. How the driver can detect which app got killed and then carry out cleanup task for removing app specific data.
I know the `.release` func ptr from `struct file_operations` is called and driver is notified, but not sure on how the drv can find the specific app that got killed.

Thanks
Sheetal

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning up on the "app" (or process) level is tricky because the process context that calls the `.release()` handler is not necessarily the same one that called the `.open()` handler. (For example, the process that called `open()` could fork a child process and exit, leaving the child running as a daemon process.)

I would recommend cleaning up on an "open file description" level instead. Every successful `open()` call creates an open file description, and the `.release()` handler is called when there are no more references to that open file description. You can use the `private_data` member of `struct file` to point to a private data structure allocated by the `.open()` handler. That "open file specific" data structure can have a member that points to your device-specific, private data structure.

As a practical example, I did the above in the kernel code for the "Comedi" subsystem. Its `.open()` handler `comedi_open()` (see [drivers/staging/comedi/comedi_fops.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/staging/comedi/comedi_fops.c)) allocates a `struct comedi_file` (which the `struct file`'s `private_data` member will point to), and the `struct comedi_file` contains a pointer (member `dev`) to the device's private data of type `struct comedi_device`. Other members of `struct comedi_file` contain information that can vary on a "per open file" basis that is not shared with other `open()`s of the same file. The `struct comedi_file` allocated by  `comedi_open()` is freed by the `.release()` handler `comedi_close()` (which I ought to rename to `comedi_release` sometime!).